# SQLite - How to insert JPG image from XML file (using Delphi 2009)

Tags: xml, sqlite, delphi, delphi-2009, bmp

I need to read a JPG image stored in a XML file and insert it into a blob field in a SQLite database.

I can do parts of this already as shown in the code below but need help with putting it together. Can sombody please show me how to read the textual *bitmap* in the XML file and insert it into the blob field in the database?

This is what I can already do.

I can read the XML file using a delphi XML Data Binding unit and store textual stuff from it in the database using the following (simplified) code:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.BtnReadXML(Sender: TObject);
 var
   sql : string;
   Data : XML_Binding_Photos.IXMLSuperStarReportType;  
   RecNum : integer;

begin
Data := XML_Binding_Photos.LoadSuperStarReport ('Photos.xml'); 
Database1.Open;
try
    RecNum := 2;
    SQL := 'INSERT INTO main.Photos ( id , firstname) VALUES ( Data.record_[RecNum].ID,  Data.record_[RecNum].Fname ) ;' ;
    Query1.Close;
    Query1.selectSQL := sql; //insert the data
    Query1.Open ;
finally
    Database1.Close;
end;
end;
```

I can also insert a JPG image from disc into the database using streams like this:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Insert_JPG_PhotoFromFile(Sender: TObject);
var 
    strm : TmemoryStream ;
begin
Database1.Open;
strm := TmemoryStream.Create;
try
    strm.LoadFromFile('C:\...\testpic2.jpg');
    Query1.Close;
    Query1.selectSQL := ('INSERT INTO main.Photos (id, photo) VALUES (''999'', :photo)');
    Query1.Params.ParamByName('photo').LoadFromStream(Strm,ftGraphic);
    Query1.Open ;
finally
    strm.Free ;
    DISQLite3Database1.close;
end;
end;
```

But my XML file has a JPG image in it, encoded as follows:

```
 <Record>
    <ID>14046</ID>
    <Fname>Fred</Fname>
    <Photo>/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAE  - lots more of the same - txNxvd8dc44Htz/Ktx3Oe3T/AB96KK6DA//Z </Photo> 
  </Record>
```

I can read the characters making up the bitmap into a string or a StringStream using the XML Data Binding unit but can't seem to get it saved correctly as a blob in the database.

(I don't want to save each XML image to disc as jpg first, partly as its already on the disc in a different form and partly as there are thousands of these images in the xml file. Also, for other reasons, I do want to put the image in the database, rather than put it on disc and just store the filename)

Comment: You know how to get a stream from a file and how to store the stream into the db. So your real question can be reduced to: How to get the image data from xml into a stream. Maybe this real question leads you to the answer ;o)

Comment: After more investigation the data is probably base64 encoded and possibly jpg not bmp. I used the Indy component TIdDecoderMIME ie PhotoData := IdDecoderMIME1.DecodeString(PhotoData); and then looked at the result in hex and it starts with FFD8, which I understand means it's jpg. So I tried making a stream using  TheStream.Write(PhotoData[1], Length(PhotoData)) ; followed by  Query1.Params.ParamByName('the_photo').LoadFromStream(TheStream,ftGraphic); but I still don't get the right image in the database (there is an image there but its just coloured boxes and strange symbols

Comment: A Base64 string is an encoded stream. Just look for a base64 string to stream decoder ;o)

Comment: "Just look for a base64 string to stream decoder" ? ?  But I think I am already decoding the base64 string in the XML. Isn't that what  PhotoData := IdDecoderMIME1.DecodeString(PhotoData); does? The output of that 'looked' like bytes from a jpg ie they started with hex FFD8

Comment: Yes it does, but you did not use the result stream. You have used the base64 encoded string `TheStream.Write(PhotoData[1], Length(PhotoData)) ;`

Comment: I think I may have solved it. I needed to convert the decoded bytes back into a hex byte string using  PhotoBlobs := '';
    for i  := 0 to high(DecodeBytes) do              
            PhotoBlobs := PhotoBlobs + inttohex(DecodeBytes[i],2); and then prepend a 'x' to the string before inserting it into the blob field. I'd like to post the whole thing as an answer to help anyone else that might look for similar code but I'm not sure of the etiquette on this forum and don't want to be voted down for doing the wrong thing. Can anyone advise? should I post all the code as my own answwer?

Answer (score 0):

This works to take an image from an XLM file and insert it into a sqlite database in a blob field.

This code uses a XML Data binding unit to make it simple to read the base64 encoded image from the xml file as a string, stored in Base64PhotoData.
It then uses an Indy TIdDecoderMIME component that I put on the form ( IdDecoderMIME1: TIdDecoderMIME) to decode the base64 to a variable of type Tbytes (called DecodeBytes)
Then, to store that array of bytes in the blob field each byte needs to be converted back into hex and the whole thing prepended with 'x'  to indicate it is in hex.
This solution does not need streams (although maybe it could be converted to do so if that approach is better)

(All the quotes are single quotes)

```pascal
Procedure TForm1.btnimportphotosfromxmlClick(Sender: TObject);
 var
   sql : string;
   XMLData : XML_Binding_Photos.IXMLStarReportType;  //in  unit  XML_Binding_Photos
   i : integer;
   Base64PhotoData, DecodedPhotoData : ansistring;
   DecodeBytes: TBytes;
   PhotoBlobs : string;
begin
XMLData := XML_Binding_Photos.LoadStarReport ('Photos.xml');       //open xml as a IXMLStarReportType , created from the xml file with the XML data binding wizard
Base64PhotoData := SIMSData.record_[2].Photo;                          //get the xml photo data from xml file, in this test case the second record
DecodeBytes := IdDecoderMIME1.DecodeBytes(Base64PhotoData) ;  //decode base64 charater string to an array of bytes

PhotoBlobs := '';                                           //initialsise the string we are going to insert into the blob field
for i  := 0 to high(DecodeBytes) do                //convert each byte to a hex charater so that it can be inserted into a blob
            PhotoBlobs := PhotoBlobs + inttohex(DecodeBytes[i],2);

SQL := ''
+'INSERT '
+'INTO   StudentPhotos ( id, photo  ) '
+'       VALUES  ( ''777'',   '
+'              x''' + PhotoBlobs +''') ' ;                         // note the prepending of lower case x to the hex byte string


DISQLite3Database1.DatabaseName := 'C:\...\testphoto.db';
DISQLite3Database1.open
try
   DISQLite3Database1.Execute(sql);
finally
  DISQLite3Database1.close;
end;
```

Comment: There is a class called `TBytesStream` and you will get a stream from the `TBytes` see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TBytesStream.Create

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that, although I'm not sure what difference using steams will make to this answer.